# The different use of Task Parallel library

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I saw few people call function using syntax like:

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => Method1(yourString1),() => Method2(youString2));
```

And few people write code like:

```
Task myFirstTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method1(5));
Task mySecondTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method2("Hello"));
```

So my question is when one should use **Parallel.Invoke()** and when one should create instance of Task class and call **StartNew()** method.

**Parallel.Invoke()** looks very handy.so what is the significance of using Task class & **StartNew()** method.........put some light and tell me the importance of different approach for same kind of job means call two function parallel with two different syntax.

i never use before the **Task Parallel library**. so there could be some hidden reason for using two approach for calling function. please guide me in detail. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `Parallel.Invoke` will block until both of the new tasks have completed.

The second approach will start two new tasks, but not wait for them to be completed. You could await them manually, or in C# 5 the new async/await feature will help you "wait" asynchronously.

It really depends what you want to do. If you *want* your thread to block until all the tasks have finished, `Parallel.Invoke` is handy.